# Lining around tub is coming off

Tags: bathtub, caulking

The lining around my tub is coming off, can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this myself?

I found a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLnVB-u0txs) on how to caulk a tub:  which I guess is what I will go with that,

but is there anything I should be extra careful with that comes to mind?

[image]

Comment: You found the correct way with her video. Preparation is the key, Scrape and clean the old caulk completely.

Comment: For future reference, that is the caulk coming off, not any sort of "lining".